# jQuery UI slider goes to -1 even if the minimum allowed is 0

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Please, can you tell me why this jQuery UI slider goes to "-1" when I move the left cursor, even if the minimum specified is "0"?

Here's the script: http://jsfiddle.net/D2FK9/

Seems very odd to me,...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce? It just goes to 0 for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, this is a known issue with this slider. See http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8108